# Wildlife in Hokkaido in November

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, photography, hokkaido

I'm trying to understand what wildlife species can be expected to be found in Hokkaido around November. Where should one travel on tge island to maximize the odds to see them.

E.g. Are there any Stellar's eagles? Is it only in Shiretoko or other places too.

I'm getting some information from searching but it's relatively minimal and sometimes in Japanese which I sadly do not understand.

Comment: What kind of wildlife are you looking for? It's a big island and you're there very much in the off season.

Comment: NHK World's English language [Wild Hokkaido!](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/wildhokkaido/) television show covers some of this type of content. It could be a good starting point for your research.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I am trying to understand what is feasible so that I can plan accordingly, I just read about the amazing biodiversity of Hokkaido and trying to understand whether I can experience it at the end of November or in the few first days of December.